# WPF Surface listbox data binding - listbox content not being populated with content

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I was using `XmlDataProvider` to get pictures from a folder, then display them in a list box, but something is wrong that list box appears but without those pictures. Pictures are in a folder called Resources in the project directory.

here are the codes, xmldata part:

```
        <!-- List content -->
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="tri" XPath="Root">
            <x:XData>
                <Root xmlns="">
                    <Entry Name="Cone" Image="\Resources\cone.jpg" />
                    <Entry Name="Cube" Image="\Resources\cube.jpg" />
                    <Entry Name="Cylinder" Image="\Resources\cylinder.jpg" />
                    <Entry Name="Icosahedron" Image="\Resources\icosahedron.jpg" />
                    <Entry Name="Octahedron" Image="\Resources\octahedron.jpg" />
                    <Entry Name="Sphere" Image="\Resources\sphere.jpg" />
                    <Entry Name="Torus" Image="\Resources\torus.jpg" />
                    <Entry Name="YinYang" Image="\Resources\yinyang.jpg" />
                    </Root>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
```

then the listbox part:

```
<s:SurfaceListBox x:Name="triList" Grid.Row="1" 
                      s:SurfaceDragDrop.DragCompleted="OntriListDragCompleted" 
                      s:SurfaceDragDrop.DragCanceled="OntriListDragCanceled" 
                      PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OntriListPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
                      PreviewMouseMove="OntriListPreviewMouseMove"
                      PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="OntriListPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource tri}, XPath=Entry}" 
                      Style="{StaticResource triListStyle}" 
                      PreviewTouchDown="OntriListPreviewTouchDown" 
                      PreviewTouchMove="OntriListPreviewTouchMove" 
                      PreviewTouchUp="OntriListPreviewTouchUp" Height="234" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Visible" ItemsPanel="{Binding}" AllowDrop="False" />
```

the list style:

```
<Style x:Key="triListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type s:SurfaceListBox }">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static s:SurfaceColors.ListBoxItemBackgroundBrushKey}}" />
            <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="234" />
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplateSelector">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <sc:triListTemplateSelector>
                        <sc:triListTemplateSelector.NormalItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <StackPanel RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"                                
                               Margin="7,0,0,0" 
                               MinWidth="171" MaxWidth="171"                                
                               MinHeight="235" MaxHeight="235">
                                    <Image Margin="14,21,21,11" Source="{Binding XPath=@Image}" 
                            Height="149" Width="101" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}" 
                             MaxWidth="116"
                             FontSize="12"                 
                             Margin="21,0,21,21"
                             FontFamily="Segoe360" 
                             TextAlignment="Center"
                             TextWrapping="Wrap"
                             Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static s:SurfaceColors.ListBoxItemForegroundBrushKey}}"  
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                </StackPanel>
                              </DataTemplate>
                        </sc:triListTemplateSelector.NormalItemTemplate>

                        <sc:triListTemplateSelector.StartingItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="17, 0, 0, -14">
                                    <StackPanel RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" 
                                Margin="7,0,0,0" 
                                MinWidth="171" MaxWidth="171" 
                                MinHeight="235" MaxHeight="235">
                                        <Image Margin="14,21,21,11" 
                           Source="{Binding XPath=@Image}" 
                           Height="149" 
                           Width="101" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}" 
                            MaxWidth="116"
                            FontSize="12"          
                            Margin="21,0,21,21"
                            FontFamily="Segoe360" 
                            TextAlignment="Center"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static s:SurfaceColors.ListBoxItemForegroundBrushKey}}"  
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static s:SurfaceColors.SurfaceWindowBackgroundBrushKey}}" 
                               Width="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-26,-2.5,0,3" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sc:triListTemplateSelector.StartingItemTemplate>                        
                    </sc:triListTemplateSelector>              

                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter> 
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <s:SurfaceScrollViewer Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                   VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                                   HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                                   CanContentScroll="True">
                            <!--<sc:LoopingPanel IsItemsHost="True" /> -->
                        </s:SurfaceScrollViewer>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

can you help me to find out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why you need the XmlDataProvider stuff for showing some images in a ListBox, but what you need is a [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms589297.aspx) with an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms610982.aspx) control that actually visualizes each image:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="imageTemplate">
    <Image Source="{Binding XPath=@Image}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

You would use that in your ListBox by setting the [ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) property:

```
<s:SurfaceListBox ... ItemTemplate="{StaticResource imageTemplate}"/>
```

---

Also make sure that the [Build Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx) is set to `Resource` for the image files in your Visual Studio project.

Comment: I guess i dont know what use datatemplate in that way you mention, since i have 2 of them in the style of trilist:

Comment: You may also post that Style. Simply edit your question and add (the relevant part of) the Style XAML.

Comment: Well, I can't guess what exactly `sc:triListTemplateSelector` does, but apparently the DataTemplates it uses do the correct `Source="{Binding XPath=@Image}"` binding. Did you make sure that the image files in your Visual Studio project have the Build Action `Resource`?

Comment: Ya, unfortunately I am sure that they are in that folder and build action is set to be resource. There exists templateselector so that either startingitem template (template for the item selected as the starting item) or normalitem template (template for items that are not the starting item) will be executed. I also set an image as a starting item.